# Django REST: Auth user is not passed to the serialiser error - Field is required

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the authenticated user is not registered in the serialiser.

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # extra code to add images
```

**views.py**

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsOwnerOrReadOnly, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(posted_by=self.request.user)
```

I don't understand why `serializer.save(posted_by=self.request.user)` doesn't work as intended. It should pass the required information about the field.

When I do a POST request, I get the error that

```
{
    "posted_by": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I think it's something to do with the `create` method in the serialiser. For some reason, `posted_by` is not present in `validated_data` (or something similar). I would like to know what exactly is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just specify `posted_by` as read only field.

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('posted_by', )
```